# Open Graph - Muliple Objects on same action

Tags: open-source, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to figure out a way to implement og action for an e-commerce site. Action would be like "Buy a Product" but usually people buys multiple products at a time by Adding different items to Cart. I do not want to show as "Jack bought xx, Jack bought yy,etc.." instead I would like to have an action like "complete purchase" where purchase is an object that might have multiple items. Any idea appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not want to show as "Jack bought xx, Jack bought yy,etc.."

Why not? You could suppress the feed story that publishing an action creates for all but the first one, and multiple actions of the same type should “fold” nicely when they are displayed on the user’s timeline, like *“John Doe bought Foobar and 16 other Products at …”*

Your other option would be to make *purchase* your object that the action is taken upon (as you already said), and then have custom properties for this object, which “link” it to other items of the type *product*. But AFAIK the number of these custom properties can not be dynamic, so you’d have to agree on a maximum number of products a purchase can contain before, which is probably not so nice. But you could set up *purchase* as an object that links to a page of your own that displays *all* products bought, and have the purchase object only contain the first (cheapest/most expensive/…) *X* of those as custom properties.

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt answer, CBroe! For the 2nd option where "purchase" is an object and custom property as "item", is it possible to get more than one value for item property moreover is it possible have sub-properties (lets say property of property) such as item's price, item's quantity, etc. - Appreciate that

Comment: Yeah, that should be possible - _purchase_ references some _items_ as custom properties, and these items themselves again have custom properties such as price, etc. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-objects/#custom